# Why do I get the false Output?

Tags: python

I tried the Euler Project Problem #11. I wrote my Code and it seems correct to me... I don't know exactly where my mistake is.

```
smallArray = []

grid = """08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48"""

gridArray = grid.split("\n")

for i in range(len(gridArray)):
    #make 2d array
    smallArray.append(gridArray[i].split(" "))
    
#smallArray[y][x]


def horizontalCheck(smallArray):
    maxHorizontal = 0
    checkSum = 1
    
    for i in range(len(smallArray)):
        for j in range(len(smallArray[i]) - 3):
            checkSum = 1
            for k in range(j, j + 4):
                checkSum *= int(smallArray[i][k])
                if checkSum > maxHorizontal:
                    maxHorizontal = checkSum
                elif int(smallArray[i][j]) != 0:
                    checkSum //= int(smallArray[i][j])
    return(maxHorizontal)

def verticalCheck(smallArray):
    maxVertical = 0
    
    for i in range(len(smallArray) - 3):
        for j in range(len(smallArray[i])):
            checkVerticalSum = 1
            for k in range(i, i + 4):
                checkVerticalSum *= int(smallArray[k][j])
            if checkVerticalSum > maxVertical:
                maxVertical = checkVerticalSum
            elif int(smallArray[i][j]) != 0:
                checkVerticalSum //= int(smallArray[i][j])
    return maxVertical

def diagonalCheck(smallArray):
    maxDiagonal = 0
    
    for i in range(len(smallArray) - 3):
        for j in range(len(smallArray) - 3):
            checkDiagonalSum = 1
            for k in range(4):
                checkDiagonalSum *= int(smallArray[i + k][j + k])
            if checkDiagonalSum > maxDiagonal:
                maxDiagonal = checkDiagonalSum
 
            if k < 3 and int(smallArray[i + k][j + k]) != 0:
                checkDiagonalSum //= int(smallArray[i + k][j + k])
    
    return maxDiagonal
            
            
def oppositeDiagonalCheck(smallArray):
    maxDiagonal = 0
    
    for i in range(len(smallArray) - 1, 2, -1):
        for j in range(len(smallArray[0]) - 1, 2, -1):
            checkDiagonalSum = 1
            for k in range(4):
                checkDiagonalSum *= int(smallArray[i - k][j - k])
            if checkDiagonalSum > maxDiagonal:
                maxDiagonal = checkDiagonalSum
 
            if k < 3 and int(smallArray[i - k][j - k]) != 0:
                checkDiagonalSum //= int(smallArray[i - k][j - k])
    
    return maxDiagonal            
                  
print(horizontalCheck(smallArray))
print(verticalCheck(smallArray))
print(diagonalCheck(smallArray))
print(oppositeDiagonalCheck(smallArray))
```

The code should check horizontal,vertical and diagonal and find the largest product of 4 adjacent numbers. But my output and what the euler project wants, differs from another. My highest output is from the vertical check. I tried to ask ChatGPT but it couldnt find a mistake

Comment: Don't make us guess what the problem is.  Show us the actual output of this code, and explain exactly how that output is different than what you expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: 51267216 this is my output. I dont know what the output should be, because you only know it when you put the correct one on the website. https://projecteuler.net/problem=11

Comment: @001 thats why I said what my code should do

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add missing info. Also, check whether your code conforms to [mcve]. That said, if you don't even know what the output should be, why do you think it's wrong? Further, that `grid` is pretty large, can you perhaps come up with a smaller case, one that's trivial to do by hand? You could then verify the results of your code.

Comment: Hey Ulrich, the Grid is given by the Euler Project Website. The task is, to find the largest product of 4 adjacent numbers. If you think you have the product, you can submit it to the website. But you only get told if youre right or wrong.

Comment: This is an excellent time to do a minimal example. You have no idea if your code works on a massive grid. Why not create a grid with an obvious correct solution, that you can work out by hand? If you have a properly built algorithm that does not depend on the size of the grid, then if it works for a small grid, it should work for a large grid.

Comment: You still have not told us what the exact problem is.  Does your code fail the horizontal check?  Does it fail the vertical check?  Does it fail the diagonal check?  What is the exact output of your code for those three cases?

Comment: `checkSum //= int(smallArray[i][j])` What is the purpose of this line?  Why are you dividing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: _I think_ they are trying to use a sliding window technique, but incorrectly. I'm not even sure if you can because multiplying by `0` will be a problem. @user23360810, try to solve the problem using a more straightforward method first, then optimize.

Comment: @001 You don't have to @ when you're commenting on a question they asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `oppositeDiagonal` checking is wrong.

Instead of exploring `(x,y), (x+1,y+1), (x+2, y+2), (x+3, y+3)`, you are exploring `(x,y), (x-1,y-1), (x-2, y-2), (x-3, y-3)`.

That is just checking the same diagonal in another direction. But that is the same as the other diagonal.
You can easily check that you get the same result from both `*DiagonalCheck`.

You should be exploring `(x,y), (x+1,y-1), (x+2, y-2), (x+3,y-3)` (or, that's the same, with a shift, `(x,y), (x-1, y+1), (x-2, y+2), (x-3, y+3)`)

My version

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[int(x) for x in s.split()] for s in grid.split('\n')])
(h,w)=a.shape
(s1,s2)=a.strides
# Max horiz 48477312
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(h,w-3,4), strides=(s1,s2,s2)).prod(axis=2).max()
# Max vert your 51267216
maxvert=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(h-3,w,4), strides=(s1,s2,s1)).prod(axis=2).max()
# Max diag 40304286
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(h-3,w-3,4), strides=(s1,s2,s1+s2)).prod(axis=2).max()
# Max antidiag  70600674 (probably expected answer)
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a[3:], shape=(h-3,w-3,4), strides=(s1,s2,-s1+s2)).prod(axis=2).max()
```

Since I get the same maximum as you do, when I ignore antidiag, that's a lazy way to confirm the diagnostic: your code (and mine) are probably ok, but for your code missing the antidiag part (computing twice, in different orders, the diagonal case).